# Insert an HTML file into a JSON file value using JQ

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq, jive

### Goal

My goal is to push HTML content to the Jive content-management platform using the Jive API and a cURL command.

### Current status

I can do this successfully but my process is manual. I want to further automate by scripting the insertion of the HTML into the JSON file Jive requires to post HTML content through the API.

### JSON file example

```
{
    "entityType": "document",
    "content": {
        "type": "text/html",
        "text": "ENCODED HTML FILE CONTENT AS A STRING"
    },
    "type": "document",
    "subject": "Document Title",
    "visibility": "place",
    "parent": "https://<URL>/api/core/v3/places/1579"
}
```

### HTML file example

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<h1 id="example">Sample file</h1>
    <p>Sample text</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">

etc.
```

### cURL example

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d @file.json "https://<URL>/api/core/v3/contents/12204"
```

The Jive API [does not turn a standalone .html file sent over the API into HTML content](https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/developer/blog/2015/06/24/upload-a-local-file-using-the-jive-api) but rather treats it as any uploaded binary file, which must be downloaded by the user.

### Attempts to solve

A [similar question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273218/jq-read-txt-file-and-write-the-values-to-json-file) asks about inserting a .txt file in the same manner. The accepted answer suggests that I try:

```
jq --slurpfile text file.html '.text=$text' file.json >newfile.json
```

I have tried surrounding the file with quotes (after it is encoded and stringified), which also failed.

### Why cURL and JQ

The reason I am looking for a JQ + cURL solution is that both JQ and cURL can be run with a Bash script, which is the only programming I know.

### Bonus question

To make the HTML file an encoded string, I run `sed 's/&/\&amp;/g; s/"/\\\"/g; s/'"'"'/\\\'"'"'/g'` and remove all the hard returns. I believe JQ's raw input and slurp options can solve this with something like `jq -Rs '{ text: . }' file.html` (according to this [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359437/read-files-into-json), and JQ offers an [@json](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual) method that escapes HTML, but after many web searches and attempts I have failed at both. It would be nice to run one JQ command that both encoded/stringified the HTML *and* inserted the HTML into the .json file.

### If this is the wrong approach entirely...

The solutions described in this question are my attempt to solve my problem and I invite a broader perspective as to whether my basic assumptions and approach are inferior to other potential approaches.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your HTML file is short enough it can fit into a command line:

```
jq --arg text "$(<file.html)" '.content.text=$text' file.json >newfile.json
```

Alternately, running an extra copy of `jq`, but working with files of any size:

```
jq --slurpfile texts <(jq -Rs file.html) '.content.text=$texts[0]' file.json >newfile.json
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Charles Duffy!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the "Bonus Question" about encoding the HTML file, you could simply use the filter `@html`, e.g.

```
.content.text=($text | @html)
```

From the online manual:

> @html:
>
> Applies HTML/XML escaping, by mapping the characters <>&'" to their
>   entity equivalents <, >, &, ', ".

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you @peak.