# Inserting a long HTML file to a Json file using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to insert the content of a long html file to my json file using the command I found on this [Insert an HTML file into a JSON file value using JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953147/insert-an-html-file-into-a-json-file-value-using-jq)

I'm using this command because the other ones are meant for short argument only, whereas in my usecase, the html content can be quite long.

`jq --slurpfile texts <(jq -Rs file.html) '.body=$texts[0]' file.json >newfile.json`

however, I'm getting this error

```
jq: error: file/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
file.html
jq: 1 compile error
```

the content of the html file doesn't seem to matter. I tried using only a simple html file like this

```
<html>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

And still got the same error.

btw before I do the jq command I'm using `sed 's/&/\&amp;/g; s/"/\\\"/g; s/'"'"'/\\\'"'"'/g'` to make the html file an encoded string as described in the same question I linked as well

What exactly am I doing wrong? the error message doesn't really say anything other than that, so I'm clueless as to what went wrong

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a filter in the inner jq call. Insert the [identity filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Identity:.) `.` as in `jq -Rs . file.html`:

```
jq --slurpfile texts <(jq -Rs . file.html) '.body=$texts[0]' file.json >newfile.json
```

Additional notes:

You could also use `--argfile` instead of `--slurpfile` which gives you the string itself rather than an array, from which you wouldn't  have to extract the first element `.[0]` anymore:

```
jq --argfile texts <(jq -Rs . file.html) '.body=$texts' file.json >newfile.json
```

Also, if you are using jq 1.6, there's yet an easier way to do it. Use `--rawfile` instead of `--argfile` or `--slurpfile` and you don't need the other jq at all anymore:

```
jq --rawfile texts file.html '.body=$texts' file.json >newfile.json
```

Comment: thank you! this worked! I double checked the answer on the link I shared and it's also missing that filter! no wonder